# Phonegap/vue js nothing appear on my android phone (withscreen) but it works on my browser

Tags: javascript, android, vuejs2, phonegap

I'am doing a cross-platform application (android/ios), so I am using phonegap and vue js.

I run phonegap serv on my ubuntu with: `sudo phonegap serv`

If I go on the ip (that phonegap tell me) on my phone with the phonegap app I have nothing, just white screen, but on my browser everything works well.

I tried to use weinre to see my log (in the html I mask my ip that why I put a X but in my real file is just my ip), but in my console log I have nothing, but in inspector if I go on the div  and I click on it my screen phone became blue (like when you inspect a web page) so I think the debugger work but not the console.

here my index.html:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Vue Stack 2.0</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/app.css">
    <script src="http:/X:8080/target/target-script-min.js#anonymous"></script>
            <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
        <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no" />
        <!-- WARNING: for iOS 7, remove the width=device-width and height=device-height attributes. See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-4323 -->
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />

</head>
<body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script> 
<!-- 
  <script src="js/materialize.js"></script>
        <script src="js/validate.js"></script>
 -->    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
        <!-- <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-validator@2.1.7/dist/vue-validator.min.js"></script> -->

    <script type="text/javascript">
    app.initialize();
    $(document).bind("mobileinit", function() {
        $.support.cors = true;
        $.mobile.allowCrossDomainPages = true;
    });
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

my config.xml:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="com.phonegap.Societhy" version="1.0.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:gap="http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0">
    <name>Societhy</name>
    <description>Hello World sample application that responds to the deviceready event.</description>
    <author email="support@phonegap.com" href="http://phonegap.com">PhoneGap Team</author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true" />
    <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="14" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-battery-status" source="npm" spec="~1.1.1" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-camera" source="npm" spec="~2.1.1" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-media-capture" source="npm" spec="~1.2.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-console" source="npm" spec="~1.0.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-contacts" source="npm" spec="~2.0.1" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" source="npm" spec="~1.1.1" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-device-motion" source="npm" spec="~1.2.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-device-orientation" source="npm" spec="~1.0.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-dialogs" source="npm" spec="~1.2.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-file" source="npm" spec="~4.1.1" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-file-transfer" source="npm" spec="~1.5.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-geolocation" source="npm" spec="~2.1.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-globalization" source="npm" spec="~1.0.3" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-inappbrowser" source="npm" spec="~1.3.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-media" source="npm" spec="~2.2.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-network-information" source="npm" spec="~1.2.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" source="npm" spec="~3.2.1" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-vibration" source="npm" spec="~2.1.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" source="npm" spec="~1.2.1" />
    <icon src="icon.png" />
    <platform name="android">
        <icon density="ldpi" src="www/res/icon/android/drawable-ldpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="mdpi" src="www/res/icon/android/drawable-mdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="hdpi" src="www/res/icon/android/drawable-hdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="xhdpi" src="www/res/icon/android/drawable-xhdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="xxhdpi" src="www/res/icon/android/drawable-xxhdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="xxxhdpi" src="www/res/icon/android/drawable-xxxhdpi-icon.png" />
        <splash density="land-ldpi" src="www/res/screen/android/drawable-land-ldpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-mdpi" src="www/res/screen/android/drawable-land-mdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-hdpi" src="www/res/screen/android/drawable-land-hdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-xhdpi" src="www/res/screen/android/drawable-land-xhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-xxhdpi" src="www/res/screen/android/drawable-land-xxhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-xxxhdpi" src="www/res/screen/android/drawable-land-xxxhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-ldpi" src="www/res/screen/android/drawable-port-ldpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-mdpi" src="www/res/screen/android/drawable-port-mdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-hdpi" src="www/res/screen/android/drawable-port-hdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-xhdpi" src="www/res/screen/android/drawable-port-xhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-xxhdpi" src="www/res/screen/android/drawable-port-xxhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-xxxhdpi" src="www/res/screen/android/drawable-port-xxxhdpi-screen.png" />
    </platform>
    <platform name="ios">
        <icon height="57" platform="ios" src="www/res/icon/ios/icon.png" width="57" />
        <icon height="114" platform="ios" src="www/res/icon/ios/icon@2x.png" width="114" />
        <icon height="40" platform="ios" src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-40.png" width="40" />
        <icon height="80" platform="ios" src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-40@2x.png" width="80" />
        <icon height="50" platform="ios" src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-50.png" width="50" />
        <icon height="100" platform="ios" src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-50@2x.png" width="100" />
        <icon height="60" platform="ios" src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-60.png" width="60" />
        <icon height="120" platform="ios" src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-60@2x.png" width="120" />
        <icon height="180" platform="ios" src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-60@3x.png" width="180" />
        <icon height="72" platform="ios" src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-72.png" width="72" />
        <icon height="144" platform="ios" src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-72@2x.png" width="144" />
        <icon height="76" platform="ios" src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-76.png" width="76" />
        <icon height="152" platform="ios" src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-76@2x.png" width="152" />
        <icon height="29" platform="ios" src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-small.png" width="29" />
        <icon height="58" platform="ios" src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-small@2x.png" width="58" />
        <icon height="87" platform="ios" src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-small@3x.png" width="87" />
        <splash height="1136" platform="ios" src="www/res/screen/ios/Default-568h@2x~iphone.png" width="640" />
        <splash height="1334" platform="ios" src="www/res/screen/ios/Default-667h.png" width="750" />
        <splash height="2208" platform="ios" src="www/res/screen/ios/Default-736h.png" width="1242" />
        <splash height="1242" platform="ios" src="www/res/screen/ios/Default-Landscape-736h.png" width="2208" />
        <splash height="1536" platform="ios" src="www/res/screen/ios/Default-Landscape@2x~ipad.png" width="2048" />
        <splash height="768" platform="ios" src="www/res/screen/ios/Default-Landscape~ipad.png" width="1024" />
        <splash height="2048" platform="ios" src="www/res/screen/ios/Default-Portrait@2x~ipad.png" width="1536" />
        <splash height="1024" platform="ios" src="www/res/screen/ios/Default-Portrait~ipad.png" width="768" />
        <splash height="960" platform="ios" src="www/res/screen/ios/Default@2x~iphone.png" width="640" />
        <splash height="480" platform="ios" src="www/res/screen/ios/Default~iphone.png" width="320" />
    </platform>
    <platform name="wp8">
        <icon height="99" platform="wp8" src="www/res/icon/wp8/ApplicationIcon.png" width="99" />
        <icon height="159" platform="wp8" src="www/res/icon/wp8/Background.png" width="159" />
        <splash height="1280" platform="wp8" src="www/res/screen/wp8/screen-portrait.jpg" width="768" />
    </platform>
    <platform name="windows">
        <icon height="150" platform="windows" src="www/res/icon/windows/Square150x150Logo.scale-100.png" width="150" />
        <icon height="30" platform="windows" src="www/res/icon/windows/Square30x30Logo.scale-100.png" width="30" />
        <icon height="50" platform="windows" src="www/res/icon/windows/StoreLogo.scale-100.png" width="50" />
        <splash height="300" platform="windows" src="www/res/screen/windows/SplashScreen.scale-100.png" width="620" />
        <icon height="120" platform="windows" src="www/res/icon/windows/StoreLogo.scale-240.png" width="120" />
        <icon height="44" platform="windows" src="www/res/icon/windows/Square44x44Logo.scale-100.png" width="44" />
        <icon height="106" platform="windows" src="www/res/icon/windows/Square44x44Logo.scale-240.png" width="106" />
        <icon height="70" platform="windows" src="www/res/icon/windows/Square70x70Logo.scale-100.png" width="70" />
        <icon height="71" platform="windows" src="www/res/icon/windows/Square71x71Logo.scale-100.png" width="71" />
        <icon height="170" platform="windows" src="www/res/icon/windows/Square71x71Logo.scale-240.png" width="170" />
        <icon height="360" platform="windows" src="www/res/icon/windows/Square150x150Logo.scale-240.png" width="360" />
        <icon height="310" platform="windows" src="www/res/icon/windows/Square310x310Logo.scale-100.png" width="310" />
        <icon height="150" platform="windows" src="www/res/icon/windows/Wide310x150Logo.scale-100.png" width="310" />
        <icon height="360" platform="windows" src="www/res/icon/windows/Wide310x150Logo.scale-240.png" width="744" />
        <splash height="1920" platform="windows" src="www/res/screen/windows/SplashScreenPhone.scale-240.png" width="1152" />
    </platform>
    <access origin="*" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
    <platform name="android">
        <allow-intent href="market:*" />
    </platform>
    <platform name="ios">
        <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
        <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
    </platform>
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-statusbar" spec="~2.2.3" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview" spec="https://github.com/crosswalk-project/cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview">
        <variable name="XWALK_VERSION" value="23+" />
        <variable name="XWALK_LITEVERSION" value="xwalk_core_library_canary:17+" />
        <variable name="XWALK_COMMANDLINE" value="--disable-pull-to-refresh-effect" />
        <variable name="XWALK_MODE" value="embedded" />
        <variable name="XWALK_MULTIPLEAPK" value="true" />
    </plugin>
</widget>
```

my app.js:

```
import { Vue, router, store } from './boot/core'
import App from './components/app.vue'
import io from 'socket.io-client';
import VueSocketio from 'vue-socket.io';
import VueToastr from '@deveodk/vue-toastr'
// You need a specific loader for CSS files like https://github.com/webpack/css-loader
// If you would like custom styling of the toastr the css file can be replaced

var Vue = require('vue');
var VueCookie = require('vue-cookie');
//require('jquery-toast-plugin')

var socketio = io('http://localhost:4242/');


// Tell Vue to use the plugin
Vue.use(VueSocketio, socketio);
Vue.use(VueCookie);
Vue.use(VueToastr, {
    defaultPosition: 'toast-top-right',
    defaultType: 'info',
    defaultTimeout: 4000
});


var vm = new Vue({
    router : router,
    el: 'app',
    render: h => h(App),
    data: { store },
    sockets:{
    connect: function(){
      console.log('socket connected');
    },
    sessionId: function(val){
      console.log('sessionId');
      console.log(val);
      this.store.sessionId = val;
    },
    txResult: function(val){

      console.log(val)
      console.log("txResult");
      this.$toastr('success', 'Success', val.event);
      this.store.txResult = val.event;
    }
    },
    methods: {
        /**
        * The Application method
        *
        * @module App
        */

         /**
        * @method getJSONData
        * @param {Object} object - data
        * get the json of a data
        */
        getJSONData(json) {
            if (this.isPhoneGap()) {
                console.log("PJSON: " + json.data)
                console.log("PJSON: " + json.data.toString())
                return json.user;
            }
            else {
                console.log("BJSON: " + JSON.parse(json.data))
                console.log("BJSON: " + JSON.parse(json.data).toString())
                return JSON.parse(json.user);
            }
        },

        /**
        * @method ajaxRequest
        * Basic ajax request for the edition 
        */
        ajaxRequest(type, route, params, success, error) {
            var res = "";
            var url = 'http://localhost:4242/login';
            var xhr = $.ajax({
                url: route,
                async: false,
                dataType : "json",
                type: type,
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                xhrFields: { withCredentials: true },
                crossDomain: true,
                data: JSON.stringify(params),
                beforeSend: setAuthToken,
                success: success,
                error: error,
                cache: false,
            })
        },

        /**
        * Set the token of authentification
        * @method setAuthToken
        * @param {Object} json object who contains the token
        */
        setAuthToken(request) {
            if (this.store.auth_data != null) {
                request.setRequestHeader("Authentification", this.store.auth_data.token);
            }
        },
        /**
        * Check if the application turn on phonegap
        * @method isPhoneGap
        */
        isPhoneGap() {
            return (window.cordova || window.PhoneGap || window.phonegap) 
            && /^file:\/{3}[^\/]/i.test(window.location.href) 
            && /ios|iphone|ipod|ipad|android/i.test(navigator.userAgent);
        },

        /**
        * Set the auth data
        * @param {Object} json object with all the information about the user
        * @method setAuthData
        */
        setAuthData(_auth_data) {
            this.store.auth_data = _auth_data;
        },
    }
})

window.vue = vm;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to download the script to local folder and changed the link accordingly. I also recommend loading cordova.js first (before any other script). So something like this:

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/target-script-min.js#anonymous"></script>
</head>
```